# WPBakery Page Builder grid builder custom image field display url not html image

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, visual-composer

1. I created a "post grid" of WPBakery Page Builder Wordpress plugin.
2. I created a new grid template in the post grid.
3. Then I add the "custom field" for display.
4. I add Toolset Types "post field" slug as the custom field of "Field key name", it is ok for text but for the image, it displays image URL, not image tag. How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you done any code for it? If so please refer that.

Comment: Not yet, I just select custom field and add post field slug with the prefix "wpcf-". The problem is that text is ok, but for an image, it renders URL, not image tag. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Then how you are expecting that to come !!! You need to write some code to grab it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added shortcode of post field(i use the custom fields from Ultimate Field Wordpress plugin).